# Simulating a Keypad with Raspberry PI

Tags: keyboard, input-device

I have an electronic Lock I want to open with my Raspberry PI 3B+. Therefore I measured the Voltage that is sent from the Keypad to the Lock. Each Number has its own Voltage. (0 = 0.00V, 1 = 0.06V... etc*). If no Signal is sent the Voltage is 3.46V. When I send the Code 1-1-1-1-1-1 (= 6 x 0.06V) with the keypad, the Lock unlocks. But when I send the same Voltage with the Raspberry PI it doesnt unlock. I measured it with my Multimeter and the Voltage is the same like with the Keypad.

The Python Script I use is very simple:

```
sgn = PWMLED(26) 
sgn.value = 1    # 3.28V
```

Depending on the Voltage I want to send I change the value.

I also connected a Capacitator (10µF, 50V) to stabilize the Signal.

Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong?

Picture of the Keypad-Board:
[image]

I analyzed the Signal of the Keypad with piscope. This is the Result of pressing 4 times the Number "1" with different keydown-Time:
[image]

**Power Supply of the Lock**

The Lock is powered by a 9 Volt Block. As you can see in the attached Foto, there is a 4-Pin-Plug.

```
9 Volt
Signal Input
Signal Output
Ground
```

In my Configuration the PI is only connected with the Ground and the Signal Input. I also tested connecting it with the Output-Pin to receive the Back-Signal which works to read the Signal with piscope.

A positive Feedback are two Beeps and a flashing Led on the Keypad. Duration is less than 0.5 Seconds. The Signal sent by the Lock is visible here:

This seems to be a correct Signal:
[image]

A negative Feedback is one long Beep and a flashing Led on the Keypad. Duration is around 1 Second.
This is the Feedback if you send a Signal when the Lock is locked (it locks you out after a couple of wrong attempts).
[image]

(* measured on the GND and the Signal Input Cable going from the Keypad to the Lock

Comment: Are you sure there's no modulation?  Use an oscilloscope rather than a multimeter.

Comment: What exactly do you consider unusual? Probably you are right. It has an usual 3x4 matrix with resistors like any ordinary Keypad. But the signal Output is in one Cable only.

Comment: @Chenmunka I dont have an Oscilloscope, sorry. I am not sure.

Comment: please include a picture of the keypad circuitry

Comment: thats the keypad-board: https://imgur.com/ET2qukt

Comment: I would first use an oscilloscope and a logic analyser to find out what the keypad **really** sends to the lock. Maybe it's not only the voltage, what counts, but the signal is in fact PWMed or frequency-controlled. And: Please post the model names / numbers of your lock and keypad.

Comment: Ok, so I will look to get an Oscilloscope/Logic Analyzer. The Lock is a M-Locks EM3520 and the Keypad is a M-Locks(?) DE2030.

Comment: Can do it via USB gadget mode:-  https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/

Comment: One can sometimes make up for lack of an O scope with a multimeter, using both DC and AC modes especially when the signal shape is known.  Here it should be known if pwm signal, filter circuit, and current capabilities are known.  (You may be running into a current limit as the buttons with resistors can likely provide more than a pi's gpio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keypad looks like it uses a voltage divider to generate a voltage signal.  One resistor stays constant while the other resistor is connected when its corresponding button gets pushed.  Depending on where you inject your signal, you may have to account for that "constant" resistor in your filter.

Voltage dividers have an advantage over switching supplies (pwm behaves closer to a switching) in that voltage is extremely stable at steady load.  If the system downstream is using the instability to determine pulses, and you have already maxed the Pi pwm frequency and are using an appropriate resistor-capacitor filter, you may have no other option than to use a different circuit.

The most surefire way to get this to work, given that it works with the keypad, would be to essentially copy the keypad.  You would need to use mosfets in place of the buttons and replicate the voltage divider resistors.  Each 'button' would then be controlled via an individual pin and mosfet on the pi.

There are other possible methods, but it really depends on why your filtered pwm is failing to replicate the keypad signal.  If the filter is incorrect (most typical error is too big a capacitor or too slow a pwm since the resistor is usually an adjustable potentiometer tuned get as close to the desired result as possible)

If it is that the current is insufficient, you may need to draw power from the keypad's battery over a mosfet to make up for it.  This can also be done via an op amp in buffer configuration.

If the signal is not smooth enough you may need a better filter.  To diagnose this issue, you might see if the keypad is registering more than one digit per press (It would lock you out before all keys were pressed).  You can use op amps to subtract off a high frequency component.  There will likely be side effects at the rise and fall however.

That leads in to the next problem.  The rise and fall may not be correct for what the device needs to separate digits.  Depending on which edge it samples, you have to get the line voltage to the desired signal voltage immediately before or after the edge.  A resistor capacitor filter with pwm start and end may not be sufficient.  You may have to use the filtered pwm as an analog source and an additional pin to start/stop the connection to that source over a mosfet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure your lock doesn't react to a voltage level, otherwise it would be useless: connecting it to a charging capacitor will sweep through all possible voltage levels and inevitably open your lock without the need to know the code.

Your lock certainly uses some sort of digital communication protocol to encode the digits you push on the keypad. I2C is a likely candidate, but UART/SPI and even pulse length or PWM-based codes are not out of the question. There's no way to find out which one it is without at least some sort of logic analyzer / scope.

You could start by turning a Raspberry Pi into a logic analyzer using [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html). If the encoding is really simple (like pulse length proportional to the digit value) and the signal is slow, it could be enough. The next step would be to buy an actual logic analyzer which can decode digital protocols for you. The cheapest legal options start at about $100 (cheapest Saleae and BitScope stuff). There are Saleae clones with prices around $10 (make no mistake: using those with official Saleae software is piracy). Those come with built-in decoders for common protocols, so if your lock uses one of those, you'll be able to figure it out.

Finally, if your lock manufacturer decided to obfuscate the digital interface, you won't be able to decode the protocol automatically. You'll have to analyze it by recording the signals corresponding to each button and figure out how it is constructed.

PWM and common protocols such as I2C/SPI/UART are also present on the Pi, so once you figure out which one it is, you might be able to interface the lock with the Pi directly. For custom protocols, you might be out of luck. As a last resort I would try is to bit-bang those custom signals using SPI (if the signal is on a single wire). If that fails, you'll likely need custom hardware to talk to the lock.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, thank you for your good Answer. I checked your Idea with piscope. I put a Picture of the Output in my Posting. There is nothing to see. I am going to check the Signal with a Logic Analyzer soon.

Comment: @Bernhard does the length of the pulse reflect the duration of the press, or is it fixed? Does the last press count as dialing "1" two times? If the signal is analog, you will not see it with a logic analyzer, which only gives out logical levels (high/low).

Comment: No its not fixed. I pressed the button three Times normal and one Time longer. Every Pulse you see is one Time pressing it. The length of the Pulse equals the Length of "keydown"-Time. I will get the Analyzer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

### Analyzing the circuit

Because you provided a high resolution image of the front and the back of the board, we can use this to examine the circuit a bit.  The conventional way to wire a 12-key keypad is to have 4 row and 3 column vectors and attach all of them to a microprocessor.  However, another way to encode key values is via an analog voltage.  This has the advantage that it now only requires a single input to read the keyboard.  Based on your report it seems clear that this is using the latter scheme.  Looking closely at the component side of the board, we can clearly see that behind each button is a via (where the conductor passes from one side of the board to the other) which connects to one side of a resistor.  Further, all of these resistors are connected to each other on the opposite side, and that also goes to the third pin of the four pin connector (numbering from upper left to lower right).  I'm guessing that side is ground, because you report that the 0 key corresponds to 0V.  Given that, it's almost certainly a simple voltage divider with one of the other resistors on the board (probably the 7500 ohm resistor closest to the right of the black IC at the top).  Assuming a conventional 12-key layout, the resistors are shown in the picture below (some resistors are rotated to more easily read their markings).

[image: resistor images]

### Resistor values

Some of these are marked with [EIA-96](http://kiloohm.info/eia96-resistor/95A) markings and others use the [4-digit SMD](http://kiloohm.info/smd4-resistor/5231) markings.  Both are indications that these are 1% resistors, meaning that they have a value within 1% of the marked value.  The values, and the key numbers are summarized in the chart below:

[image: resistor values chart]

As you can see, The values approximately follow an exponential curve which is probably intended to make the voltages easier for the mysterious semiconductor device in the upper part of the board to distinguish the different voltages and therefore keys.

[image: exponential curve fitting]

### Getting analog voltages from a Raspberry Pi

As you have already discerned, one of the easiest ways to get an analog voltage from a Raspberry Pi is to use the PWM output and filter it.  You say that you have a capacitor to "stabilize the signal" but don't mention a value.  The value is important for a few reasons.  If the value is too large, the capacitor will take too long to charge; if it's too low, you will not filter out the chopping frequency of the PWM and the lock with "perceive" this as multiple button presses.  The design of just this part of the circuit [is not trivial](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34843/how-determine-the-rc-time-constant-in-pwm-digital-to-analog-low-pass-filter) if you want it to work properly.  Rather than discuss all of that here, I'm going to make some guesses as to what is wrong and suggest a few possible solutions.

### Theory #1: missing pause

From your description, the lock requires a pause between each digit.  Otherwise it would be unable to distinguish between a single long button press and six presses of the same button.  Make sure you are pausing (from the signal trace, that appears to mean "voltage is high") between each simulated button press.

### Theory #2: wrong filter time constant

The next possibility is that the filter time constant is wrong.  As I mentioned above, with the link, there is a both science and art to choosing the right values.  A simple [circuit for filtering PWM](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=124130) might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa6BS8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Depending on the frequency of the PWM and the duty cycle you choose, it may be difficult to get this to work well enough for this purpose.  One way you might approach this with only an digital voltmeter is to try some values of R and C and observe both the DC voltage out (your target voltage) and then also the AC voltage (which would give an indication of ripple).

### Theory #3: unpowered lock

Of course, in order for an electronic lock to function it must have power. You don't say where exactly you're measuring the voltages, and don't specify how the lock is powered when the Pi is connected.  If it's getting the right input signal but is otherwise unpowered, it's never going to work.  You also don't say what power source the lock uses, but as always, it's important to assure that the Pi **never** has more than 3.3V GPIO pin.

Comment: Hello Edward, thank you for your extensive Answer! I updated my Question.

Comment: Note that "exponential' resistors values may fit the design of a [voltage ladder](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/559653/72179) which produce evenly distributed voltage steps for each button.